# Настройка callback для VK

Tags: vkontakte-api, api

Меня интересует метод https://vk.com/dev/groups.setCallbackSettings и https://vk.com/dev/groups.getCallbackSettings что за server_id которое должно быть положительным числом, Я же могу именовать сервера как мне захочется. И не указывается это в адресе даже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каждый раз, когда вы создаёте новый сервер в админке группы, ему присваивается уникальный номер, он совпадает с порядком создания (отсчёт начинается с 1). Увидеть идентификатор можно в адресной строке:

```
https://vk.com/club1?act=api&server=4
```

Если `&server=X` не отображается, то, наверное, сервер будет доступен по идентификатору `1`.

Ещё этот идентификатор возвращается при создании нового сервера через API: [`groups.addCallbackServer`](https://vk.com/dev/groups.addCallbackServer).

Одновременно не может быть более 10 серверов, однако `server_id` может быть сколь угодно большим, если предыдущие сервера были удалены. Он отражает лишь порядковый номер по очереди.